# turn "terminal code" into "text editor code" on Mac

Tags: python, terminal

This might be a really stupid question, but I want to take code that's written in a way that would be run through terminal and put it into a .py file.

The code is:

```
$ python -m sesame.targetid --mode predict \
                            --model_name fn1.7-pretrained-targetid \
                            --raw_input sentences.txt
$ python -m sesame.frameid --mode predict \
                           --model_name fn1.7-pretrained-frameid \
                           --raw_input logs/fn1.7-pretrained-targetid/predicted-targets.conll
$ python -m sesame.argid --mode predict \
                         --model_name fn1.7-pretrained-argid \
                         --raw_input logs/fn1.7-pretrained-frameid/predicted-frames.conll
```

Is it possible to somehow translate this so I could put it in a text editor and save it as a .py file, so then I could simply run the whole thing in terminal by using

```
$ python myfile.py
```

Comment: Why don't you just make a `bash` script that executes those commands?

Comment: That is not Python code. If anything you'd put that as is into a .sh file and run it as bash script. Translating this into equivalent Python code depends on how that library translates those specific command line arguments into function calls internally.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than putting that into a Python file, I'd put those commands into a shell script. Seeing that it looks like you're on a Unix system, you can use this:

```
#!/bin/sh
python -m sesame.targetid --mode predict \
                          --model_name fn1.7-pretrained-targetid \
                          --raw_input sentences.txt
python -m sesame.frameid --mode predict \
                         --model_name fn1.7-pretrained-frameid \
                         --raw_input logs/fn1.7-pretrained-targetid/predicted-targets.conll
python -m sesame.argid --mode predict \
                       --model_name fn1.7-pretrained-argid \
                       --raw_input logs/fn1.7-pretrained-frameid/predicted-frames.conll
```

You'll need to be in the same directory that you'd normally run those Python scripts when running this.

Then you can either run `sh myfile.sh` or you can use `chmod u+x myfile.sh` to make it an executable, then you'll be able to run `./myfile.sh`.

The first line, `#!/bin/sh`, is a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)). It tells the shell what program to use to execute the file. It's not necessary if you use `sh myfile.sh` to run it, but it can't hurt since it's essentially a comment in `sh`.